# Confusing recursive behaviour

Tags: go, recursion, sequence, callstack

I am trying to figure out stuff about recursion (I am studying go)
and by playing around I did this.
[playground](https://play.golang.com/p/tjFNG745mQO)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    recurse(0)
}

func recurse(i int) {
    if i >= 6 {
        return
    }
    i++
    fmt.Println(i)
    recurse(i)
    rerecurse(i)
    fmt.Println(i)
}
func rerecurse(i int) {
    i++
    recurse(i)
}
```

and this give this:
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 3, 1`

[image]

Then I got really confused it get really long if you increase the ceil value (e.g. from 6 to 20)
It does not look like there is any order in that sequence, can any of you shed some light on it?
By the way any good resource to share on how call stack works so I can understand recursion instead of admitting it?

Comment: You might find it easier to understand if you record the steps taken [for example](https://play.golang.com/p/DaMUplhJRGM).

Comment: The output makes perfect sense. Maybe add a fmt.Println("recursion depth hit") before the return statement and also fmt.Println("re") just before calling rerecurse so it's easier to follow through

Comment: Thanks, I start to understand.
Each function call go to the end, but in between there is nested recursion that will be called and "die".
for each step going down we produce a "rebound" that extend the loop.